# stop ant if a class returns -1 calling System.exit(-1) in its main

Tags: java, ant

I found many thread about handling test fails but I did not find a way to stop ant if a "java" ant task finishes with the class returning -1 (or any other error value).

I do not want to use junit task because it is not a unit test as the user has to enter some input. The class in its main method checks the code on the basis of the input and eventually returns an error calling System.exit(-1).

In that case I need to stop ant.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: a class does not return value, please elaborate

Comment: sorry I meant a class that has a main method that calls System.exit(-1). I call that class with the <java> ant-task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [failonerror attribute](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) of the java task.

```
 <java failonerror="true" fork="true" ... />
```

This will fail your build (default is "false") if the returncode is **other than 0**.

#### Note: You need to run with fork="true".

Or use [fail](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) with [conditions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)

```
  <java resultproperty="result" fork="true" ... />
  <fail>
     <condition>
       <equals arg1="${result}" arg2="-1"/>
     </condition>
   </fail>
```

Comment: are you sure? I need to call java MyClass. In that case the exec task will check the value returned by java

Comment: @herschel sry I misread for exec at first, but the java task behaves nearly the same. I updated my answer.

Comment: are you sure it should be true? I think that fork should be set to false

Comment: @herschel I am pretty sure that the complete JVM(including ant) will exit on System.exit if you don't fork.

Comment: It looks like if I set it to true the user is not able to enter the input anymore. I presume that the input is sent to the first JVM instead of the new one

Comment: @herschel seems to be a [bug in 1.8.2](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50960) :(